# My Visual Studio 2012 program works in Debug, release without debug (ctrl + F5) but not release. How do I fix?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, release

As stated above my program works in Debug and Release without debug (ctrl + F5) however does not work in simply Release.

Just to clarify I have already checked to see if I have some uninitialized variables  and I haven't (to the best of my knowledge anyway but I have spent quite some time looking).

I believe to have localized the issue and what I have come across is, in my opinion, very bizarre. First I set up the break points as shown in the picture below:

[image: Break Point set up]

Then I run the program in release. And instantly the top break point moves:

[image: Moving breakpoint]

I found this extremely odd. Now note the number 6302 assigned to 'n'. This number is correct and what I hoped to pass through. Now watch as I continue through the program.

[image: n = 6302]

We are still in good shape but then it turns for the worst.

[image: n explodes]

'n' changes to 1178521344, which messes up the rest of my code.

Would someone be able to shed some light on the situation, and even better, offer a solution.

Thanks, 
Kevin

Here is the rest of the function if it helps:

```
NofArr = n;

const int NA = n;
const int NAless = n-1;

double k_0 = (2*PI) / wavelength;       
double *E = new double[NAless];             // array to hold the off-diagonal entries
double *D = new double[NA]; // array to hold the diagonal entries on input and eigenvalues on output
int sizeofeach = 0;
trisolver Eigen;                    

int* start; int* end;

vector< vector<complex <double>> > thebreakup = BreakUp(refidx, posandwidth, start, end); 

for(int j = 0; j < (int)thebreakup.size(); j++){

    // load the diagonal entries to D
    for(int i =0; i < (int)thebreakup[j].size(); i++){
                D[i] = -((double)2.0/(dx*dx)) + (k_0*k_0*thebreakup[j][i].real()*thebreakup[j][i].real());
        }

    // load the off diagonal
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)thebreakup[j].size(); i++){
        E[i] = (double)1.0 / (dx*dx);
    }

    sizeofeach = (int)thebreakup[j].size();

    double *arr1= new double[sizeofeach];

    arr1 = Eigen.EigenSolve(E, D, sizeofeach, mode);

    complex <double> tmp( PhaseAndAmp[j][1]*cos(PhaseAndAmp[j][0]), PhaseAndAmp[j][1]*sin(PhaseAndAmp[j][0]));

    // rebuild the break up with the mode
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)thebreakup[j].size(); i++){
        thebreakup[j][i] =  (complex<double>(arr1[i],0.0)) * tmp ;
    }

    delete []arr1;
}

vector<complex<double>> sol = rebuild(thebreakup, start, end);

delete [] E;
delete [] D;
delete [] start;
delete [] end;
return sol;
```

Comment: [OT]: it seems you can pass your vector by const reference. `E` and `D` may be `std::vector<double>` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Are you sure that `NA` and `thebreakup[j].size()` are equal ?

Comment: The reason for the first breakpoint moving is that the first two statements generate no code - the compiler will just substitute those variables with `n` when needed. Similar for the last image - perhaps `n` isn't needed anymore and the compiler is reusing the memory space?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jarod42 but I need to use raw pointers as I use E and D in LAPACK later. Also thebreakup[j].size() is not the same size.

Comment: You may still use `std::vector::data()` once a `double*` is required.

Comment: Don't post code as pictures please. That's not what you have achieved that privilege for.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks !! Makes sense about the breakpoint. I'm not so sure about the 'n'. I actually looked further into the code. The "yellow arrow" seems to move down AND up ? Would you know why this is ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Apologies but I wanted to make reference to the breakpoints and variables at the bottom. How could I show this without pictures ? For future improvements.

Comment: @KevinSynnott - The optimizer can move the code around as it sees fit, to make it run faster. That can make the arrow move both up and down.  :-) In your case, I would try to step through the code in debug mode to figure out what it does exactly. Even though it seems to work overall, there is a bug in there somewhere. But hard for us to tell from just 10 lines...

Comment: @BoPersson Oh cool, I had no idea. Yes 10 lines isn't too much to go off. Apologies. Just one more question on the optimizer if you don't mind. Why would my code work in release without debugging, thats ctrl + F5 ?

Comment: You probably have memory corruption somewhere. In debug-mode, the data structures aren't as tightly packed, so you might not notice the error. The same happens when running your program under the debugger or not - a slightly different heap is used, which may result in you not noticing the memory corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered my mistake. Earlier in the program I was comparing pointers, not what they were pointing at. A stupid mistake but one I wouldn't have spotted without a long debugging session. My boss explained that the information given at the bottom of Visual Studio whilst in release mode cannot be trusted. So to "debug" I had to use `std::cout` and check variables that way.

So here is the mistake in the code:

```
if(start > end){
        int tmp = start[i];
        start[i] = end[i];
        end[i] = tmp;
    }
```

Where `start` and `end` were defined earlier as:

```
int* start = new int[NofStacks];
int* end = new int[NofStacks];
```

And initialized.

Thanks to all those who helped and I feel I must apologise for the stupid error.

The Fix being:

```
 if(start[i] > end[i]){
        int tmp = start[i];
        start[i] = end[i];
        end[i] = tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as an answer, because it's way harder to write as a comment.

What strikes me immediately is the array "arr1"

First you allocate new memory and store a pointer to it in the variable arr1

```
double *arr1= new double[sizeofeach];
```

Then, immediately, you overwrite the address.

```
arr1 = Eigen.EigenSolve(E, D, sizeofeach, mode);
```

Later, you delete something. Is it safe?

```
delete []arr1;
```

It's not the double array you allocated, but something eigensolve returned. Are you sure you have the right to delete it? Try removing the delete here. Also, fix the memory leak too, by removing allocation in the first line I gave.

---

What worries me even more is that the "this" pointer changes. There is some nasty problem somewhere. At this point, your program has already been corrupted. Look for the issue somewhere else. Valgrind would be a GREAT tool if you can try to compile under linux.

Comment: I played around with the arr1 but to no avail. I think you are right about the "this" pointer. Prior to posting the question I tried to change my "this" pointer. Again no luck. Just to get a better understanding of the "this" pointer, is it just the variables I have in header file and that I initialize in the constructor ?

Comment: "this" should not change mid function, ever(?). If it does, something is very badly wrong. Most likely a memory corruption has occurred. Most likely cause for this is that you have freed memory you should not free. Maybe the issue rises from something you do before calling this function. Can you produce a simple example program we can test? I have no idea what to pass to your function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some sort of code optimization going on in your program. It is not always easy to debug optimized code step-by-step since the optimization may reorder instructions.
I cannot see why the fact that 'n' changes to an apparently uninitialized value would be the root cause of the problem, since 'n' is anyways no longer used in your function. Seems like the memory is simply been released as part of the optimization.